# How to handle response in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am new to react. Currently I am working on creating a login screen. I have this code:

```
function login(e) {
    fetch('/login')
      .then(response => {
        if(response === 'fail'){
            return(SignIn());
        }else{
            return(Ide());
        }
      })
      .then((proposals) => { 
        console.log(proposals);
        this.setState({ proposals }); 
      });
  }
export default function SignIn() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
      <CssBaseline />
      <div className={classes.paper}>
        <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
        </Avatar>
        <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
          Sign in
        </Typography>
        <form className={classes.form} noValidate>
          <TextField
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
            required
            fullWidth
            id="email"
            label="Email Address"
            name="email"
            autoComplete="email"
            autoFocus
          />
          <TextField
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
            required
            fullWidth
            name="password"
            label="Password"
            type="password"
            id="password"
            autoComplete="current-password"
          />
          <Button
            type="submit"
            fullWidth
            onClick={login}
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            className={classes.submit}
          >
            Sign In
          </Button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </Container>
  );
```

And then the login handler

```
app.get('/login', (req, res, next) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  console.log(email, password); 
  //User.find({email: })
});
```

But when I press the submit button, email and password both console log as undefined. How do I send information using react between the client and the server? Thank you in advance

Comment: Wait what? Did you even make a response? Is it just a `if` statement?

Comment: I did not, when I hit submit it sends a fetch request for '/login' which then runs the code below, which just console logs ' undefined undefined'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214291/discussion-between-zixuan-and-the-traveling-coder).

Comment: I've down voted as rude behavior is unacceptable, people are trying to help here and **for free**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you use fetch as a way to send info to an endpoint like '/login' above, the req.body needs to be added as part of the fetch call. To do this, people usually do

```
fetch('/login', {
body: (whatever you send in the form of one object)
});
```

The body passed in as the second argument can be then used as req.body in your code that console.logs it.

This is not advised though since GET commands usually do not have bodies passed along as the second argument. Usually POST and PUT commands have the body to make it easy to add and change data. What I recommend is do:

```
fetch('/login/' + email + '/' + password);
```

This allows for an email and username object to be a part of your url in for your backend to use. This is one of the ways that people do GET commands without passing in a body. With the new format, you should change the backend to be:

```
app.get('/login/:email/:password', (req, res) => {
const email = req.params.email;
const password = req.params.password;
console.log(email, password);
```

With :email and :password in the url, this lets you use req.params and then directly call each identifier as the last value.

Btw if you feel like the fetch call above looks messy with the + commands, you can instead do:

```
fetch(`/login/${email}/${password}`);
```

Which are [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) that make it easier to read code by adding the values directly into the string. (Note they use the ` key next to the 1 key not ' or ")

Also if you want more info on fetch commands, I advise to start with the [MDM Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). This website is extremely helpful whenever you need to learn something about JS or other web languages.